# Makefile metaprogramming: template targets based on other target prerequisites expansion

Tags: makefile

I'm trying to improve the legacy of a project where I have lot of libraries.

For each library `foo` we have several targets (eg `mrproper-foo`).

We build several different products (eg `foobar`) which rely on several of the libraries (eg `foo` and `bar`).

What I want to achieve is `make` to automatically generate the `mrproper-foobar` targets which would call the corresponding `mrproper-foo` and `mrporper-bar`.

In the dummy example below, my base targets `foo,bar,do-foo,do-bar` are explicitly given. I want make to implicitly understand any target that would be created:

```
foo:
        @echo $@

bar:
        @echo $@

do-foo: foo
do-bar: bar

foobar: foo bar
barfoo: bar foo

.SECONDEXPANSION:
do-%: $$(addprefix do-,$$*)
        @echo "stem: "
        @echo $*
        @echo "prerequisites: "
        @echo $^
```

For both `foobar` and `barfoo` (and any other `barfoobar` and others explicitery created), I want make to resolve them as `do-$(barfoo)`->`do-bar do-foo`. Plus, when an explicit target is given (like for `do-bar`) I don't want make to call the implicit rule…

The given example won't work:

```
make do-bar
make: Circular do-bar <- do-bar dependency dropped.
bar
stem:
bar
prerequisites:
bar
```

In this case, make applies the implicit rules and the info on the circular dependency seems to indicate that the `addprefix` function works. But trying to call an implicitly created target fails:

```
$ make do-barfoo
make: *** No rule to make target `do-barfoo'.  Stop.
```

Any hint?

---

## edit

Updated question title

Comment: I suspect that your are trying to achieve this complicated thing while there is a much simpler make feature that could fulfil your initial need. Can you explain what your real need is?

Comment: @RenaudPacalet I've updated my question with explanation of my goal (taken from my previous comment [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46791081/makefile-metaprogramming-template-targets-based-on-other-target-prerequisites-e#comment80565949_46791300).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can probably get something close to what you want with conditionals and recursive make:

1. Enclose your explicit root targets (`foo`, `bar`, `do-foo`, `do-bar`) in a conditional that evaluates true by default (the true mode).
2. Leave your compound targets (`foobar`, `barfoo`) outside any conditional.
3. Enclose all other targets (`do-%` and `%`) in a conditional that evaluates false by default (the false mode).
4. In the true-conditional add a `do-%` last default target that just invokes make again with the same goal in false-mode.
5. Add a `%` last default target in the false-conditional with no prerequisites and a recipe that just prints "`$@`" (space-target).
6. Add a `do-%` rule in the false-conditional with no prerequisites and a recipe that:

   - invokes make again, in false mode, with the `$*` (the `%` pattern) goal to get all prerequisites (direct or indirect),
   - processes it to remove the `%` pattern,
   - adds the `do-` prefix to all remaining elements and, finally,
   - invokes make once more in true mode with the resulting `do-*` elements as goals.

Something like:

```
MODE    := true

ifeq ($(MODE),true)

foo:
    @echo $@

bar:
    @echo $@

do-foo: foo
    @echo $@

do-bar: bar
    @echo $@

do-%:
    @$(MAKE) MODE=false $@

endif

foobar: foo bar
barfoo: bar foo

ifeq ($(MODE),false)

do-%:
    @targets="$$($(MAKE) --no-print-directory MODE=false $*)" && \
    targets="$${targets/ $* / }" && \
    targets="$${targets/% $*/}" && \
    targets="$${targets/# $*/ }" && \
    targets="$${targets// / do-}" && \
    $(MAKE) MODE=true $$targets

%:
    @printf " %s" "$@"

endif
```

When invoking make with a non-explicit `do-foobar` goal make will:

1. start in true mode and invoke itself again in false mode with goal `do-foobar`
2. run the `do-%` recipe of false mode that will invoke make once more in false mode with goal `foobar` to get the prerequisites of `foobar` (plus `foobar` itself), and set the `targets` shell variable successively to:

   - `" foo bar foobar"`
   - `" foo bar"`
   - `" do-foo do-bar"`
3. invoke make one last time in true mode with goal `do-foo do-bar`

All other (explicit) targets should be processed normally. But this is really complicated. Not sure I would use it myself...

Note: the sequence of parameter expansion - substitution in the complex `do-%` recipe looks a bit cryptic but bash manual section EXPANSION, sub-section Parameter Expansion, explains all this. Here is a short overview where `stem` is the pattern that matches `do-%` (`$*`) and `_` represents a space:

- `targets="$${targets/ $* / }"` substitutes `_stem_` with `_`
- `targets="$${targets/% $*/}"` substitutes `_stem` at the end of `targets` with nothing
- `targets="$${targets/# $*/ }"` substitutes `_stem` at the beginning of `targets` with `_`
- `targets="$${targets// / do-}"` substitutes all `_` with `_do-`

So, if `targets` is `foo bar foobar`, the first substitution does nothing, the second changes `targets` into `foo bar`, the third does nothing and the last changes `targets` into `do-foo do-bar`. But if the members in `targets` are in a different order things still go fine.

Comment: I really like your answer but I'm still confused by all that is happening with the `targets` variable and how you get the prerequisites. Maybe you could add some comments on this to make it clearer?

Comment: running `make do-foobar`  results in `make[2]: *** No rule to make target 'make[2]:'.  Stop.`. Have I missed something?

Comment: @Vser What happens with the `target` shell variable is just bash parameter expansion and substitution. I admit that it looks a bit cryptic but if you read the bash manual, section `EXPANSION`, sub-section `Parameter Expansion`, it should become clear.

Comment: @Vser Amazing! I tested with `make --no-print-directory do-foobar` to get rid of useless messages and... it works. But if I `make do-foobar`, I encounter the same problem as you do. Looks like a bug. Let me investigate a bit.

Comment: @Vser Fixed: the `--no-print-directory` make option was missing in the `do-%` complex recipe. Make was thus echoing directories traversal and this was interfering with the computation of `targets`.

Comment: I'm just realizing the fact that your `targets`  bases itself on the fact that I'm echoing `$@` in my example to get the list of prerequisites (am I right?)! At first I thought it was some kind of `make` black magic but after you told me it's simply some bash expansion I realized this won't work in other cases where the targets may echo a lot more than just `$@`. I fear there is no *makeish* way to get the list of prerequisites of a target (I could use `grep` but this is the start of hell, right?)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157070/discussion-between-renaud-pacalet-and-vser).

Comment: My previous comment is false: we get the prerequisites in the false mode thanks to the `%:` mode that prints the target name and thus reconstruct the list of prerequisites!

Answer (score 0):

`do-barfoo` target will not be generated, even during the secondary expansion, simply because it does not exist as a target: it has never been defined or listed as a prerequisite of any other target.

Comment: So there is no implicit way to achieve what I want? I'll have to explicitly add `do-barfoo: do-bar do-foo` for any new `barfoo` command I'll add?

Comment: @Vser I guess you could write a rule where do-barfoo is listed as a prerequisite. It would then be generated, and exitsts. `special: do-barfoo do-foobar`.

Comment: I've been working on using eval and came up with a partial answer. Do you have any idea of how to improve it?

Comment: @Vser I'm still wondering what you are trying to achieve with this ... What is your goal?

Comment: I'm trying to improve the legacy of a project where I have lot of libraries where for each library `foo` we define several targets (eg `mrproper-foo`. We define different products (eg `foobar` which rely on several of the libraries (eg `foo` and `bar`) and I want make to automatically generate the `mrproper-foobar` targets which would call the corresponding `mrproper-foo` and `mrporper-bar`. It appears many of the said dependencies have been forgotten in the development history and this would be a solution to solve this. But maybe I'm on the wrong path…

Answer (score 0):

I came up to a partial solution using the `eval` function:

```
PROGRAMS = foobar barfoo
foobar_dep = foo bar
barfoo_dep = bar foo

foobar: $(foobar_dep)
barfoo: $(barfoo_dep)

LIBRARIES = foo bar

.PHONY: all
all: $(PROGRAMS) $(LIBRARIES)

foo:
        @echo $@

bar:
        @echo $@

do-foo: foo
do-bar: bar


define do-PROGRAM_template
do-$(1): $(addprefix do-,$($(1)_dep))
endef

# Uncomment the next line if you want to see what targets are generated
#$(foreach prog,$(PROGRAMS),$(info $(call do-PROGRAM_template,$(prog))))
$(foreach prog,$(PROGRAMS),$(eval $(call do-PROGRAM_template,$(prog))))
```

This will auto generate `do-<target>` for every target listed in `PROGRAMS`.

However, this is still not perfect:

- I don't know how to get the prerequisites of `foobar` so I'm defining `foobar_dep` and use it as an input to create the target (I could create a similar eval function to define the `<target>` but my users would have to define their targets as `target_dep =` (maybe `target =`would be enough) but that would be a strange way to define a target and thus would be prone to errors…
- I have to list all the targets in `PROGRAM`, it would be cool to not have to add this step so that my users just have to add a single line `foobar: foo bar` and not predeclare it in `PROGRAMS`.

Any hint to improve this answer?